# How I define nqueen's moveFactory in OptaPlanner?

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am studying OptaPlanner from example.

I am trying to setup moveFactory in the nqueen example. I've modified the config file as follows:

```
<moveListFactory>
  <moveListFactoryClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nqueens.solver.move.factory.RowChangeMoveFactory</moveListFactoryClass>
</moveListFactory>
```

I compiled and ran the nqueens and the following exception occurred :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The moveSelectorConfigList ([ChangeMoveSelectorConfig(null, null), MoveListFactoryConfig(class org.optaplanner.examples.nqueens.solver.move.factory.RowChangeMoveFactory)]) must be a singleton or empty. Use a single UnionMoveSelectorConfig or CartesianProductMoveSelectorConfig element to nest multiple MoveSelectors.
at org.optaplanner.core.config.localsearch.LocalSearchPhaseConfig.buildMoveSelector(LocalSearchPhaseConfig.java:243)
```

How I can specify the moveFactory correctly ?
I am using optaplanner-distribution-7.7.0.Final.

Thanks,
MH

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 move selectors, wrap them in a `<unionMoveSelector>`. I 'll make the error message more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I put  like the following:

```
<unionMoveSelector>
  <changeMoveSelector>
    <selectionOrder>ORIGINAL</selectionOrder>
  </changeMoveSelector>
<!-- changeMoveSelector is the generic form of RowChangeMoveFactory: -->
  <moveListFactory>
    <moveListFactoryClass>org.optaplanner.examples.nqueens.solver.move.factory.RowChangeMoveFactory</moveListFactoryClass>
</moveListFactory>
```

Then, it requires . I added it like this.

```
<acceptedCountLimit>10</acceptedCountLimit>
```

Then, it worked.